# Something similar?

Tags: pseudocode

I'm in my first year and I have to do some problems in a new programming language invented by my teacher which is very similar with java

The problem is: Write a program that asks the user to enter a number. It will then repeatedly display the message "hello" twice the number of times as the number entered. So if you entered 3 it should print "hello" 6 times.

So far I did this:

```
get number
set p=number*2
for p=1 to 100
 repeat 
  display "hello"
 until number !=p
endfor
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: So we have to guess what this new language, invented by your nameless teacher, which looks nothing like java, does?

Comment: you immediately set p to be twice the value of number, so your until will fail immediately.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because answering questions about an unknown programming language are inherently impossible.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel No it isn't, not with this little amount of code

Comment: Looking at the given info, this is an NP hard problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get number
set p=number*2
for i=1 to p
  display "hello"
endfor
```

Comment: its the first time when I use this forum. Is it the green arrow ?

Comment: now its getting more complicated..its asking if the number is 5 or more it will then repeatedly display the message "hello" the number of times entered . If the number is less than 5, it should display the message hello twice the number entered.

Comment: Get number
Set p=number*2
If(number<=5)
 For i=1 to p
 riplay “hello”enfor
rlseif (number>5)
repeat 
 display “hello”
until number
endif

Comment: thats another question..

Comment: shall I open another topic question?